# Being able to delete a certain result from an SQL while loop

Tags: php

I have looked around for an answer but cannot seem to find one.

I would like to be able to delete a specific query from the database.

How am I able to remove a specific one from the form and post it into an SQL statement to delete?

Here is my current select statement.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo "Hello!";
  $selectOption = $_POST['info'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `REQUESTS` ORDER BY $selectOption"; 
  echo $query;
  $result = $db->query($query);
  if ($result == FALSE) { 
        die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
  } 
    else
  echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
  echo "<table>";     
  while($row=$result->fetchRow()){ 

  if ($row['status'] == 0) {
      $type="rejected";
  }
  else if ($row['status'] == 1){
      $type="pending";
  }
  else if ($row['status'] == 2){
      $type="accepted";
  }


  echo "<tr id=".$type."><td>" . $row['requestid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['booking_type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['moduleid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['no_rooms'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['park'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['semester'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['day'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['start_time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['end_time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['length'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['students'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";


  // <td class="'.(($row['status'] == 2) ? 'status-rejected' : 'status-accepted'). '">'.$row['status'].'</td>';
  echo "<td>".$stats."</td>";*/
  echo "<td>" . $row['round'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date_submitted'] . "</td>";
  }

  echo "</tr>";

  echo "</table>"; 
  echo "</form>";
}
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to add a form to each table row with a hidden element containing the id of that row. When clicked, you would use that row's id to call a delete query. In addition, you're mixing and mashing terminology pretty badly. You want to delete a specific *row*, not a result from a while loop.

Comment: Or you can do it using ajax.. Also, for security reasons, this part `die ("could not execute statement $query<br />")` should be removed from your code..

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to delete.

If you want to actually delete a data / row in your database, you need to use the **DELETE Statement** as explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

I guess your statement would look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM REQUESTS
WHERE requestid=$row['requestid'];
```

**$row['requestid']** is the actual unique key identifier to the data row you would like to delete.

edit:
You could create a button / link to the exact page with an GET data (yourpage.php?deleteid=1) to pass the id of the data you would like to delete from the database.

**Keep in mind that using GET paratemers isn't the best way to do this.** You should rather use a form and POST the regarding id.